# No scrollbar on pdf iFrame in iPad Safari, but perfect on PC Safari

Tags: html, ios, css

I am trying to embed a pdf into a webpage, but it will not scroll, not with 1 finger or 2. The funny thing is that the same page rendered on a computer has a scroll bar, but the iPad version does not. Is there a way to add the scroll bar or at least enable 1/2 finger scrolling?

My code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="pdfContainer">
        <iframe class='pdf' src="pdf1.pdf" frameborder="3"></iframe>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="pdfContainer">
        <iframe class='pdf' src="pdf2.pdf" frameborder="3"></iframe>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.pdfContainer { 
    overflow:scroll !important; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;

    width: 90%;
    height: 800px;

    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.pdf{
    width: 99%; /* should fill 99% of parent */
    height: 100%; /* should fill 100% of parent */
}
```

Does someone spot the problem? Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a mobile application, or for actual web safari? If for application, try the line

```
UIWebview* myWebview = [[UIWebview alloc] init]];
myWebview.scrollenabled = YES;
myWebview.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
```

Also make sure that you don't have the scroll off in auto layout.

If for using a website you will have to look into implementing a mobile version

Comment: Sorry for being late. Yes, this is primarily for a mobile site. I just added your script in between script tags above the HTML posted, and it doesn't seem like anything changed. What was it supposed to do? And what do you mean by having the scroll off in auto layout?

Comment: Oh now well that code is in objective-c, so that was if you were creating a mobile application. You may want to rephrase it so it's clear you're looking to do a mobile site version. This is most likely a JavaScript issue